# Pass url argument to ListView queryset

Tags: django, django-urls

**models.py**

```
class Lab(Model):
    acronym = CharField(max_length=10)

class Message(Model):
    lab = ForeignKey(Lab)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<lab>\w+)/$', ListView.as_view(
        queryset=Message.objects.filter(lab__acronym='')
    )),
)
```

I want to pass the `lab` keyword argument to the ListView queryset. That means if `lab` equals to `TEST`, the resulting queryset will be `Message.objects.filter(lab__acronym='TEST')`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Using "naked" default classes is good idea when you need something stupidly simple - return static static html or make redirect to fixed url.
Best way to do do what you want is listed in @AamirAdnan answer (also, there are a lot of examples in django tutorial and docs).

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You need to write your own view for that and then just override the `get_queryset` method:

```
class CustomListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Message.objects.filter(lab__acronym=self.kwargs['lab'])
```

and use `CustomListView` in urls also.

Answer (score 5):

```
class CustomListView(ListView):
    model = Message
    
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # either
        self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
        self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(lab__acronym=kwargs['lab'])
         
        # or
        queryset = Lab.objects.filter(acronym=kwargs['lab'])
        if queryset.exists():
            self.object_list = self.object_list.filter(lab__acronym=kwargs['lab'])
        else:
            raise Http404("No lab found for this acronym")

        # in both cases
        context = self.get_context_data()
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```

Comment: **Note:** Spelling mistake in the argument. `kwargs` instead of `kwagrs`.