# Django ListView self.kwargs

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I'm using **Django==1.11**. As I understand from class based views, in this case ListView, you can access url params in *get_queryset* with **self.kwargs**, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19361042/6005145) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36950584/6005145). And I have no problem when I use *get_context_data* and self.kwargs.

But I can't get it to work in *get_queryset*. ¿What I'm doing wrong or missing? I've been trying so many alternatives but I can't get the right one.

My code:

**urls**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^escuelas/(?P<level>(inicial|primario|secundario))/$', SchoolListView.as_view(), name='school-by-level-index'),
    #...
```

**view**

```
class SchoolListView(ListView):
    model = School
    template_name = 'edu/adminlte/school_index.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(SchoolListView, self).get_queryset()
"""
Here below self.kwargs['level'] does not return anything as I would expect
"""
        level = self.kwargs['level']

        if level is 'inicial':
            queryset = School.objects.filter(level='I')
            return queryset
        return queryset
```

Thanks.

Comment: move the `level = self.kwargs['level']` line before the `super()` call.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid nothing happened

Comment: Is the queryset returning as expected outside of the if statement? Are you sure 'level' is in the kwargs?

Comment: @leelum1 Yes the queryset works fine. If I put `level='initial'` it works, no problem with the query itself. The kwargs, as I understand should work from de url pattern, as I said with `get_context_data`, applying the same logic, it works.

Comment: Oh I understand now. How are you calling the ListView?

Comment: @leelum1 What do you mean by calling the ListView? It is in the urls pattern `SchoolListView.as_view()`. I mean, and maybe should clarify, that theres no problem either with the template display of the query (without filter). The view just don't get the parameter with `self.kwargs['level']`, so I can't filter the query from it.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was something simple:

[double equals vs is in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15008380/double-equals-vs-is-in-python)

My code was:

```
    if level is 'inicial':
```

But it had to be

```
    if level == 'inicial':
```